# Ubuntu backup asks for encryption password repeatedly

Tags: backup, gnupg, duplicity

I recently had to install a fresh Ubuntu. I have automatic backups of my old Ubuntu. I do not wish to restore to my old state. I just need to get back specific folders containing some pdfs and doc files. The backups however are all stored in a gpg format, with names such as duplicity-inc or duplicity-new-signautes. Is it possible to restore specific files from such a backup?

Edit:
I tried the Ubuntu backup, but it keeps asking me for the encryption password repeatedly.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean you don't remember your password anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore specific files from a duplicity backup. You need to enter the following command:

```
duplicity restore --file-to-restore relative/path/to/file URL /target/file
```

The `file-to-restore` must be a relative path depending from the directory where the backup is based. `URL` is a FTP-, file- or other link and `/target/file` is the place where the restored file should live.

However as you wrote in your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353720/ubuntu-backup-asks-for-encryption-password-repeatedly#comment466513_353725) when you lost your password there is not much chance to recover the backup anyway. You only can try to remember it. Maybe you wrote it down somewhere or have it in your shell history. Sometimes mistakes happen and help to recover the password.

Answer (score -1):

Scalpel is one of the best command line tool to recover deleted files in Ubuntu Linux. It can recover almost all types of files. It visits data blocks of files sequentially and identifies deleted files and recovers them instantly. You can install it by running following command in your terminal.

```
apt-get install scalpel
```

SOURCE : http://hub4pc.blogspot.in/

Comment: Scalpel doesn't help here. Judging from the question the OP forgot his password to his encrypted backup.

Comment: I do recall my password(s). I believe the problem is that I've used multiple passwords. Here's the followup question I'd asked that I haven't received a response to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/354604/used-multiple-encryption-passwords-how-to-restore